# add a column from data 2 to data 1 with multiple condition in R

Tags: r, merge, na, missing-data

I have 2 data both have different lengths and different variables.

I would like to replace the zeros in column "Speed" from DF1 with the values in "Real_Speed" column from DF2 based on matching columns: Lat, Long, Day, Month, Hour, and Minute.
But at the same time, I'd like to fill the row in the "Speed" column that still has "0" value and has the same  Day, Hour, and Minute with a value in the same range of the value in that column. Here's the code that produces the data, and the desired output.

```
DF1 <- data.frame("Lat" = rep(c("A","C","B","D")),
                  "Long" = rep(c("B","B","D","D")),
                  "Speed" = rep(c(0),4),
                  "Hour_Minute" = rep(c("1:00", "1:15", "1:30", "1:45")),
                  "Day" = rep(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)),
                  "Month" = rep(c(4),4),
                  "Year" = rep(c(2020),4),
                  "Weather" = rep(c("Clear","Rain", "Fug","Snow"),),
                  "State" = rep(c("TX","FL"),4),
                  "Country" = rep(c("USA"),4),
                  "Steert" = rep(c("Highway","BLVD"),4))

DF2 <- data.frame("Lat" = rep(c("A","B","C"),2),
                  "Long" = rep(c("B","D","B"),2),
                  "Real_Speed" = (sample(55:70,6)),
                  "Hour_Minute" = rep(c("1:00", "1:23","1:15", "1:34","1:30", "2:05")),
                  "Day" = rep(c(1,2,2,1,2,5)),
                  "Month" = rep(c(4),6),
                  "Year" = rep(c(2020),6),
                  "Side_Lane" = rep(c("Right","Left", "Right","Right","Left", "Right"),),
                  "Accident" = rep(c("Low","Sever", "Sever","Low","Low", "Sever")))
```

From DF2, I'll update the Speed column with 55, and 61:

```
Lat Long Speed Hour_Minute Day Month Year Weather State Country   Steert
A    B     55        1:00   1     4 2020   Clear    TX     USA Highway
B    D     61        1:30   2     4 2020     Fug    TX     USA Highway
```

And the rest of the rows will have a sample of values with a range of values similar to the Hour, and Day columns. The new data will be:

```
Lat Long Hour_Minute Day Month Speed Year.x Weather State Country   Steert Real_Speed 
A    B        1:00   1     4     0   2020   Clear    TX     USA Highway         55   
A    B        1:00   2     4     0   2020   Clear    TX     USA Highway         56     
B    D        1:30   1     4     0   2020     Fug    TX     USA Highway         57     
B    D        1:30   2     4     0   2020     Fug    TX     USA Highway         61   
C    B        1:15   1     4     0   2020    Rain    FL     USA    BLVD         58     
C    B        1:15   2     4     0   2020    Rain    FL     USA    BLVD         62   
D    D        1:45   1     4     0   2020    Snow    FL     USA    BLVD         60     
D    D        1:45   2     4     0   2020    Snow    FL     USA    BLVD         59
```

I tried to merge both data using this code but I get an error and tried to join left merge but It adds all the columns from DF2 and has NAs values.

```
DF3<- merge(DF1, Df2, by=c("Lat","Long" ,"Hour_Minute","Day"), all.x= TRUE)


DF3 <- merge(DF1, Df2, by.x = c("Lat","Long" ,"Hour_Minute","Day"), by.y=c("Lat","Long" ,"Hour_Minute","Day"), all.x=TRUE) %>%
  rename(Speed=Real_Speed)
```

**Update**

I added set.seed(1)

```
set.seed(1)
DF11 <- data.frame("Lat" = rep(c("A","C","B","D")),
                  "Long" = rep(c("B","B","D","D")),
                  "Speed" = rep(c(0),4),
                  "Hour_Minute" = rep(c("1:00", "1:15", "1:30", "1:45")),
                  "Day" = rep(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)),
                  "Month" = rep(c(4),4),
                  "Year" = rep(c(2020),4),
                  "Weather" = rep(c("Clear","Rain", "Fug","Snow"),),
                  "State" = rep(c("TX","FL"),4),
                  "Country" = rep(c("USA"),4),
                  "Steert" = rep(c("Highway","BLVD"),4))

DF12 <- data.frame("Lat" = rep(c("A","B","C"),2),
                  "Long" = rep(c("B","D","B"),2),
                  "Real_Speed" = (sample(55:70,6)),
                  "Hour_Minute" = rep(c("1:00", "1:23","1:15", "1:34","1:30", "2:05")),
                  "Day" = rep(c(1,2,2,1,2,5)),
                  "Month" = rep(c(4),6),
                  "Year" = rep(c(2020),6),
                  "Side_Lane" = rep(c("Right","Left", "Right","Right","Left", "Right"),),
                  "Accident" = rep(c("Low","Sever", "Sever","Low","Low", "Sever")))
```

And here is both data:

DF11

```
  Lat Long Speed Hour_Minute Day Month Year Weather State Country  Steert
1   A    B     0        1:00   1     4 2020   Clear    TX     USA Highway
2   C    B     0        1:15   1     4 2020    Rain    FL     USA    BLVD
3   B    D     0        1:30   1     4 2020     Fug    TX     USA Highway
4   D    D     0        1:45   1     4 2020    Snow    FL     USA    BLVD
5   A    B     0        1:00   2     4 2020   Clear    TX     USA Highway
6   C    B     0        1:15   2     4 2020    Rain    FL     USA    BLVD
7   B    D     0        1:30   2     4 2020     Fug    TX     USA Highway
8   D    D     0        1:45   2     4 2020    Snow    FL     USA    BLVD
```

DF12

```
  Lat Long Real_Speed Hour_Minute Day Month Year Side_Lane Accident
1   A    B         59        1:00   1     4 2020     Right      Low
2   B    D         60        1:23   2     4 2020      Left    Sever
3   C    B         63        1:15   2     4 2020     Right    Sever
4   A    B         66        1:34   1     4 2020     Right      Low
5   B    D         57        1:30   2     4 2020      Left      Low
6   C    B         64        2:05   5     4 2020     Right    Sever
```

Comment: If you want to limit the merging to only certain rows it might be better to use `match`.

Comment: Your `DF2` is not usable, `Error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 4`. Perhaps it should have `"Long" = rep(c("B","D"),3)` instead of `,2`?

Comment: Also, you define `DF2` and reference `Df2`, do you have similarly-named objects in your environment?

Comment: Lastly, is there a particular reason you have four separate columns for hour, minute, day, month, and year, instead of a single `POSIXxt` timestamp? Unfortunately we're going to be unable to reproduce your desired output since you used random values in your problem definition but did not use `set.seed`.

Comment: @r2evans, I had these variables as a single POSIXxt timestamp, but I separated them to make it easier. The DF2 is the second data and DF1 is the first data and I want to add the value of the "Real_Speed" column from DF2 to DF1, or just produce a DF3 that has the output from DF2 and DF1.  Not sure what you meant by DF2 is not usable.

Comment: @IRTFM This will add all the columns from DF2 and DF1

Comment: As @r2evans has outlined, there are some issues with your question that make it unanswerable as is. Please address these issues to clarify the question and make it reproducible or it will probably get closed.

Comment: @DanAdams thank you for notifying me. By mistake, I added the wrong data code. I just updated DF1 and DF2

Comment: Ok - please use `set.seed()` at the top to make the `real_speed = sample()` reproducible or just provide some actual values.

Comment: The `NA` values after `merge()` are expected since there are no rows in `DF12` that match **ALL** of the specified columns. Can you describe how you thought the merging process would work? Perhaps that's the root issue here. `merge(by = ...)` will require a match in **ALL** of `...`.

Comment: But I'm using `DF11 %>% select(-Speed) %>% left_join(select(DF12, Lat,  Long, Day, Real_Speed))` and assuming you have some logic as to how you want to fill in the missing `NA` values in `Real_Speed`. Can you clarify?